# C# Login screen using sql database not working

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement, string-comparison, sqldatareader

I have a simple login screen which, upon user clicking login button, should run the sql query to search for rows where the username == username text box, and password == password text box. This section of my code works fine.

However when I try to run an if statement, which will open a new form and close the login form, it errors, even though I have added some message boxes to check that the statement sting comparison is correct.

Any ideas?

Login Button:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            cn.Open();
            string userText = txtUsername.Text;
            string passText = txtPassword.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(Username, '') AS Username, ISNULL(Password,'') AS Password FROM Users WHERE Username='" + userText + "' and Password='" + passText + "'", cn);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(userText + " / " + dr["Username"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(passText + " / " + dr["Password"].ToString());
                if (dr["Username"].ToString() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString() == passText)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                    dashboard.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Login attempt:
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

With the advice taken from the Answers and Comments below the code has been corrected to the following (using sql parameters in the sql command):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            cn.Open();
            string userText = txtUsername.Text;
            string passText = txtPassword.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(Username, '') AS Username, ISNULL(Password,'') AS Password FROM Users WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userText));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", passText));

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                dr.Read();
                if (dr["Username"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString().Trim() == passText)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                    dashboard.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Try using the Trim() fn

Comment: once you get this working try putting ' where 1=1;-- into the password lol

Comment: Hi NickB can u change the condition like this from if (dr["Username"].ToString() == userText && dr["Password"].ToString() == passText)
 to if(dr["Username].ToString().Trim().Equals(userText.Trim()) && dr["Password"].ToString().Trim().Equals(passText.Trim()))

Comment: @AMR .. Not a helpful comment.. But that is hilarious

Comment: @PradipKT Oh I think it eloquently demonstrates sql injection at it's best haha

Comment: @AMR .. indeed it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a trim() on to the end of the sql return as you check them.

`dr["Username"].ToString().trim()` and  `dr["Password"].ToString().trim()`

Sometimes the Database will store extra spaces you cant see.

Comment: Chose this as an answer @NickB6

Comment: @PradipKT please don't ignore the comments on SQL-injection and save storage of passwords. The answer of ling.s shows a better solution (though not handling the SQL injection and storage issues).

Comment: @mrab I agree that he should focus his attention to learning on how to use SQL params. This program, if a real company login, is just waiting to be hacked. That said, I did answered his question :-)

Comment: This won't be used by the company haha - its a university project. They would need to be taking some serious medication to let me near any of their live code. Ps. I am by no means a developer

Comment: If you really want a good grade look at doing SQL parameters in C#. It's SUPER easy. Might be 1 extra line of code? Basically you would put @ParameterName for each parameter in your SQL Call then add one extra line of code that defines them. Then when you make your SQL call they can stick almost what ever they like in that password or username box and it's not going to break.

Comment: Cheers @AMR, very kind of you to take the time. I will check this out and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this: I think it will work

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='" + userText.toString() + "' and Password='" + passText.toString() + "'", cn);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(username + " / " + usertext);
            MessageBox.Show(password + " / " + passtext);
            this.Hide();
            Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
            dashboard.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
```